# Have biblatex output the same ordinal edition as bibtex in IEEE (bib) style?

Tags: biblatex

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{btest.bib}
@BOOK{Mittelbach2005,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach},
  edition = {2. ed.},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title = {The LATEX companion},
  year = 2005
}
\end{filecontents*}

\ifx\ubl\undefined %
  \def\tubl{bibtex}
\else %
  \usepackage[%
    style=ieee,
    isbn=true,
    doi=false,
    url=true,
    backend=biber
  ]{biblatex}
  \bibliography{btest}
  \def\tubl{bibLAtex}
\fi

\begin{document}

Citing... HERE: \cite{Mittelbach2005} (\tubl)

\ifx\ubl\undefined %
  \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS} %
  \bibliography{btest} %
\else %
  \printbibliography[resetnumbers] %
\fi

\end{document}
```

You can quickly compile it with the following `bash` one-liner:

```bash
for ib in {b,bl}; do \
  if [ "$ib" = "b" ]; then \
    TCMD='-jobname=testA "\input{test.tex}"'; \
    pdflatex $TCMD; bibtex testA; pdflatex $TCMD; pdflatex $TCMD; \
  else \
    TCMD='-jobname=testB "\def\ubl{1}\input{test.tex}"'; \
    pdflatex $TCMD; biber testB; pdflatex $TCMD; \
  fi; \
done
```

The TestB.pdf, which utilizes `biblatex`+`biber` looks like this:

[image: testB.png]

... and the TestA.pdf, which utilizes `bibtex`, looks like this:

[image: testA.png]

Note that the `bibtex` one shows "2nd ed.", while `biblatex`+`biber` one shows "2. ed.". Looking at [Biblatex customization - Thesis in LaTeX [khirevich.com]](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/), one may think this would make `biblatex` do ordinal suffixes:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}%
                   {\ifinteger{#1}%
                    {\mkbibordedition{#1}\addthinspace{}ed.}%
                    {#1\isdot}}
```

... however, that is *only* for purely numerical fields - and notice, here the field is:

```
  edition = {2. ed.},
```

... that is - it is alphanumeric; and `bibtex` seemingly parsed into it, and replaced '2.' with '2nd', and appended the rest!

So how can `biblatex` be persuaded to produce the same output as `bibtex`, "2nd ed.", from this same field?

(By the way, side question: you can notice also the spacing is different; how can I get the same spacing with `biblatex` as I get it with `bibtex`?)

Comment: The most appropriate solution would be to change the value of the field `edition` in the  bibtex entry (eventually in a dynamic way using `biber` capability to transform fields on the fly. Suppose you have  `collector edition` value for the edition. what you want is to keep the literal format, not to transform to an ordinal.

Comment: Thanks @Guido - you may be right, but `bibtex` in this case still transforms the field, and I just want to do the same in `biblatex` (while not worrying about changing .bib files). In any case, one could have a regex match `^(\d+)(.*)` - and if \1 matches (i.e. field starts with numbers), those can be extracted and transformed, and the rest appended; while for no match, the literal would be output (which is what I think also `bibtex` does). Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we commence, I would like to quote what the `biblatex` documentation says about the `edition` field

> `edition` field (integer or literal) The edition of a printed
>   publication. This must be an integer, not an ordinal. Don’t say
>   `edition={First}` or `edition={1st}` but `edition={1}`. The
>   bibliography style converts this to a language dependent ordinal. It
>   is also possible to give the edition as a literal string, for example
>   “Third, revised and expanded edition”.

So the best you could do is to make sure your `.bib` files adherer to this practice and write `edition = {2}` instead of `edition = {2. ed.}`.

We can let Biber do some of this work, however.
In this example we use a RegEx of the form `^(\d+)\.\s+(ed.|edition)$`, this will match numbers followed by a full stop some space and the word "ed." or "edition".
A more liberal RegEX might be  `^(\d+).*` which will match all numbers regardless of what they are followed by.
In any case we copy the first group into the `edition` field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=edition,
            match=\regexp{^(\d+)\.\s+(ed.|edition)$},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Mittelbach2005,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach},
  edition = {2. ed.},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title = {The LATEX companion},
  year = 2005
}
\end{filecontents*}
  \usepackage[%
    style=ieee,
    isbn=true,
    doi=false,
    url=true,
    backend=biber
  ]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\mkbibordedition{#1}\addnbthinspace\bibstring{edition}}
    {#1\isdot}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=edition,
            match=\regexp{^(\d+)\.\s+(ed.|edition)$},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
Citing... HERE: \cite{Mittelbach2005}

\printbibliography[resetnumbers] %
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, @moewe - thanks for that and sorry for the late accept! Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau It was more of a late answer than a late accept, you were actually quite quick `;-)`.